# Testmethod problem: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, unit-test, query, exception, failing-tests

I have the following method in which SOAP webservice is consumed created by wsdl2apex (only necessary part is shown):

```
public class SendOrder {

    public void SendOrder(string OrderId) {

        // Query for Order
        Order__c Order = [SELECT    Id,
                               Ship_To_SAP_Code__c,
                               Sold_To_SAP_Code__c,
                               Currency__c,
                               Purchase_Order_Number__c,
                               Requested_Shipping_Date__c,
                               Original_Requested_Shipping_Date__c,
                               Shipping_Date_Change_Reason__c,
                               Incoterm__c,
                               Payment_Type__c,
                               Vehicle_Type__c,
                               Palette_Type__c,
                               Additional_Docs__c,
                               Logistics_Company_Phone__c,
                               Logistics_Company_Email__c,
                               Logistics_Company__c,
                               Order_SAP_Code__c,
                               Source_Country_Code__c,
                               Integration_Id__c,
                               Status__c
                               FROM Order__c 
WHERE Id=:OrderId];

.
.
.
.


        // Assign request parameters
.
.
.

        inputIM_Header.INCOTERMS    =   [SELECT Name FROM List_Of_Values__c WHERE Display_Value__c=:Order.Incoterm__c AND Type__c='INCOTERM' LIMIT 1].Name;
        inputIM_Header.PMNTTRMS     =   [SELECT Name FROM List_Of_Values__c WHERE Display_Value__c=:Order.Payment_Type__c AND Type__c='PAYMENT_TYPE' LIMIT 1].Name;          
        system.debug(inputIM_Header.PMNTTRMS);

.
.
.
.


        }


}
```

I have also created a test class for this code, in which I first create a dataset and then call the above class inside it (again, only necessary part is shown):

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class SendOrder_Test {

    static testMethod void OrderTest() {

        List_Of_Values__c ListOfValue2 = new List_Of_Values__c();
        ListOfValue2.Name = 'INCO';
        ListOfValue2.Display_Value__c = 'Incoterm';
        ListOfValue2.Type__c = 'INCOTERM';
        insert ListOfValue2;
        system.debug('listofvalue2 id = '+ListOfValue2.id);

        List_Of_Values__c ListOfValue3 = new List_Of_Values__c();
        ListOfValue3.Name = 'PMNT';
        ListOfValue3.Display_Value__c = 'Payment';
        ListOfValue3.Type__c = 'PAYMENT_TYPE';
        insert ListOfValue3;
    system.debug('listofvalue3 id = '+ListOfValue3.id);

.
.
.
.


    Order__c Order = new Order__c();
    Order.ShipTo_Account__c = ShipToAccount.Id;
    Order.Currency__c = 'USD';
    Order.Source_Country_Code__c = 'TURKEY';
    Order.Requested_Shipping_Date__c = system.today();
    Order.Original_Requested_Shipping_Date__c = system.today();
    Order.Incoterm__c = 'Incoterm';
    Order.Payment_Type__c = 'Payment';        
    insert Order;
    system.debug('order id = '+Order.id);

.
.
.
.

        Test.startTest();

        SendOrder SendOrderx = new SendOrder();
        SendOrderx.SendOrder(Order.Id);

        Test.stopTest();

.
.
.
.

    }
}
```

According to the test data, inputIM_Header.INCOTERMS and inputIM_Header.PMNTTRMS queries should not return blank, because I create exact data for both of them. However, when I run the test, INCOTERMS is populated, while PMNTTRMS query does not see the test data and I get the error specified in the title.

I've made a lot of research about that;

- I had already SeeAllData on, turning it off was no help,
- I'm on SystemAdmin user so I have all the permissions,
- I debug all the test data and make sure they all are created on test
  class,
- Debugging PMNTRMS returns a data when executed from execute anonymous
  (testing with org data),
- Payment_Type__c FLS is OK for SystemAdmin

The fact that bug me most is that INCOTERMS is fine while PMNTTRMS could not be queried.

P.S. I know you are going to tell me to use List instead of a single sObject; you are right, but I am getting NO record from query at this point. I want to solve it first.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I queried for the Order test data after I inserted it inside the test class, and its Payment_Type__c picklist field was indeed null even though I defined a value for it. The solution I adopted here is: insert the order test record without defining Incoterm__c and Payment_Type__c fields, then query for this Order record, set these fields, and update.

```
Order__c Order = new Order__c();        
Order.ShipTo_Account__c = ShipToAccount.Id;
Order.Currency__c = 'USD';
Order.Source_Country_Code__c = 'TURKEY';
Order.Requested_Shipping_Date__c = system.today();
Order.Original_Requested_Shipping_Date__c = system.today();
insert Order;

Order__c OrderUpdate = [SELECT Id, Incoterm__c, Payment_Type__c FROM Order__c WHERE Id=:Order.Id];
OrderUpdate.Incoterm__c = 'Incoterm';
OrderUpdate.Payment_Type__c = 'Payment';
update OrderUpdate;
```

But I really want to know why this Payment Type picklist field did not get a value initially. I'm looking forward to clarifications on that matter.

Thanks

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/43938)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up, but my post can be viewed as a solution to my issue. This is why I chose to put an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting up the webservice mock to return your test response. You can't make callouts from test methods.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. My only problem in the test class is as I described above. When I delete the problematic line in the class, I pass the test and get 85% coverage.